# How do I send value of selected option to express

Tags: javascript, express, multer

```html
<label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">
  <strong>Enter Number of pdfs to merge</strong>
</label>
<select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1">
  <option name="number">1</option>
  <option name="number">2</option>
  <option name="number">3</option>
  <option name="number">4</option>
  <option name="number">5</option>
</select>
```

```js
app.post("/merge", upload.array("pdfs", 2), async (req, res, next) => {
  console.log(req.files);
  let d = await mergePdfs(
    path.join(__dirname, req.files[0].path),
    path.join(__dirname, req.files[1].path)
  );
});
```

I have hardcoded for 2, I wanted the user to select the number of pdfs he wants to merge

Comment: You shouldn't need `path.join()`. The Multer file object `path` property is already the full filesystem path

Answer (score 1):

1. Remove the limit in the Multer middleware.

   ```js
   upload.array("pdfs")
   ```
2. Add a `name` to your `<select>` so that it's included in the request payload

   ```html
   <select
     required
     name="limit"
     class="form-control"
     id="exampleFormControlSelect1"
   >
   ```
3. Check the `req.files` length and return an error if differs from `req.body.limit`. Then simply map over `req.files`, extract the paths and pass them to `mergePdfs()`

   ```js
   app.post("/merge", upload.array("pdfs"), async (req, res, next) => {
     const { limit } = req.body;
     if (req.files.length !== limit) {
       return res.status(400).send(
         `Expected ${limit} file(s), received ${req.files.length}`
       );
     }

     try {
       const d = await mergePdfs(
         ...req.files.map(({ path: filePath }) => filePath)
       );

       // do something with `d`
     } catch (err) {
       next(err);
     }
   ```